# Issue with 'Source not found'

Tags: java, eclipse, remote-debugging

I'm trying to debug a tomcat server. Also I have installed JadClipse in Eclipse. And I need to stop in classes which have no source file.
So. When I do 'ctrl+open implementation' on method - everything works fine(I see decompiled sources of this file). I even can put a breakpoint inside this method.
But when workflow reaches this breakpoint, it stops on it and I can't see decompiled sources.
What should I do?

And when I turn off console with launched tomcat - decompiled code comes back at the same moment.

Comment: did my answer help you or solved your question?

Answer (score 0):

I am a debugging adict an understand what your problem is.

It is easy to open and decompile classes that you navigate but it is difficult to do it while debugging it.

What you can try (it is a little tedious but works) it is doing a manual work. As you can see in below image, the **Debug** panel has different threads for you application. In this case you have a Thread with a Main class and main method, at this line you will find the  line number for the process you are debugging. For example:

*Main.main(String[])* **line: 9**

This debugging "line: 9" points you at what line in the class you are watching.

[image]

In your case, you can be guided using the line number and can use Ctrl+Open to navigate the sources. You won't see the debugging highlight since you are doing a manual work but it is really helpful to debug decompiled classes.

Hope to help.